# Search for column data to paste corresponding rows of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks. In workbook1 there is a name column A. In workbook2 there is also a name column A and other data from column B to D.

I need to search name from Column A of workbook2 in column A of workbook 1 and if the name matches paste the corresponding rows in workbook1.
Note that in workbook2 there may be more than one entry for same name. In those cases those row values must be concatenated and pasted on workbook1.

```vb
Dim AVals As New Dictionary
Dim k As Long, j As Long, lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
Dim sh_1, sh_3 As Worksheet
Dim MyName As String
Dim tmpCollection As Collection
Set sh_1 = Sheets("snipe-sample-assets blank")
Dim key As Variant

inputRowMin = 1
inputRowMax = 288
inputColMin = 1
inputColMax = 9
equipmentCol = 4
dimensionCol = 9

Set equipmentDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
equipmentDictionary.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
Set inputSheet = Application.Sheets("Verizon WirelessNumbers_2021033")
Set inputRange = Range(Cells(inputRowMin, inputColMin), Cells(inputRowMax, inputColMax))
Set equipmentCollection = New Collection

For i = 1 To inputRange.Height
    thisEquipment = inputRange(i, equipmentCol).Text
    nextEquipment = inputRange(i + 1, equipmentCol).Text
    thisDimension = inputRange(i, dimensionCol).Text

    'The Strings are equal - add thisEquipment to collection and continue
    If (StrComp(thisEquipment, nextEquipment, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
        equipmentCollection.Add thisDimension
    'The Strings are not equal - add thisEquipment to collection and the collection to the dictionary
    Else
        equipmentCollection.Add thisDimension
        equipmentDictionary.Add thisEquipment, equipmentCollection
        Set equipmentCollection = New Collection
    End If

Next
 
'Set sh_3 = Sheets("sheet2")

lastRow2 = sh_1.Range("A:A").Rows.Count
lastRow2 = sh_1.Cells(lastRow2, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column 2
'MsgBox lastRow2

For j = 2 To lastRow2
    MyName = UCase(sh_1.Cells(j, 2).Value)
    For Each key In equipmentDictionary.Keys
        If (StrComp(MyName, key, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
            Set tmpCollection = equipmentDictionary.Item(MyName)
            For k = 1 To tmpCollection.Count
                sh_1.Cells(j, 10).Value = tmpCollection.Item(k)
            Next
        End If
        
    Next
    
Next j
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Have you been able to open and read cells from both workbooks in VBA?

Comment: I brought both workbooks data onto one workbook in different sheets..  but not able to implement above logic

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be aware that SO is meant to be an assistance repository. So it would help if you can show what code you have already tried. What errors do you get, what solutions have you tried etc. Without any code at all nobody will be able to assist. Moreover, this question, or similar ones have been asked many times. Have you done any research on how others have solved the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=copy+paste+data+from+one+column+to+another+excel+vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick run down of what you need

```
'You declare all these based on where your data resides
sheetName1 = "Sheets1"
sheetName2 = "Sheets2"
wbName1 = activeworkbook.name
wbName2 = activeworkbook.name   'I've included this for where you might want to fork solution to work off two workbooks

'Loop through entries in sheetName1
iRows1 = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(workbooks(wbName1).sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRows1,1))
    sourceName = workbooks(wbName1).sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRows1,1)

    'Loop through entries in sheetName2
    colB = ""
    colC = ""
    colD = ""
    iRows2 = 1
    Do Until IsEmpty(workbooks(wbName2).sheets(sheetName2).cells(iRows2,1))
        if workbooks(wbName2).sheets(sheetName2).cells(iRows2,1) = sourceName then
            'If there is a match then append. If you want to delimit, then you'd need to add in a delimiter & "," for example
            colB = colB & workbooks(wbName2).sheets(sheetName2).cells(iRows2,2).text
            colC = colC & workbooks(wbName2).sheets(sheetName2).cells(iRows2,3).text
            colD = colD & workbooks(wbName2).sheets(sheetName2).cells(iRows2,4).text
        end if
        iRows2 = iRows2 + 1
    Loop

    if colB <> "" then
        'Found something, send it to sheetName1
        workbooks(wbName1).sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRows1,2) = colB
        workbooks(wbName1).sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRows1,3) = colC
        workbooks(wbName1).sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRows1,4) = colD
    end if

    iRows1 = iRows1 + 1
Loop
```

If you want to do it for separate workbooks, then you need to assign a wbName2. My use of ActiveWorkbook assumes it'll be run out of the workbook you are pasting to. It also assumes you've opened both workbooks. You can figure that bit out yourself I'm sure.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your quick response and help.. but it did not work!! may be because in sheet2 there are more than one names with multiple entries.. for example              ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
Elezar     xyx Iphone7
Elezar dfd Ipad
John fgf Laptop
Peter  fdf Iphone 
Peter fgm Laptop                                                                                                              Now i need to search these names in Sheet1 and append ColumnC values together and paste in the last column available on Sheet1

Comment: What did it do? It should have added them together as I did not stop the for loop upon first match...

Comment: Just did a test, and it worked exactly as I expect it to...? Any matching entries to ColA in Sheet1 had their corresponding entries in Cols B-D in Sheet2 copied into Cols B-D of Sheet1 and multiple matches in Sheet2 were copied and concatenated.